# How to access conditional items in dictionary that is in a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

```py
empty_list=[]
employee = [{
    "name" : "Nauman",
    "age" : 27,
    "Salary": 29000
},
    {
        "name": "Bilal",
        "age": 26,
        "Salary": 27000
    },
    {
        "name": "Ali",
        "age": 19,
        "Salary": 22000
    },
    {
        "name": "Usman",
        "age": 28,
        "Salary": 34000
    },
    {
        "name": "Usama",
        "age": 14,
        "Salary": 24000
    }
]

def function(employee):
    for value in employee:
        if employee.my_dict(["age"])>25 and employee.my_dict(["salary"])>25000:
            empty_list.append(employee)
print(empty_list)
```

Comment: First of all you never called your function. Also you need to indicate that you're using a global variable (*although its not a good practice to use a global variable*) and also `value` represents each dictionary thus you can't access the fields as is at the moment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can correct and improve your code as follows:

1. Pass your data as an argument to your function rather than trying to access the global variable directly.
2. Access each employee from your list of employees and then use the relevant keys to access the desired data e.g. `employee['age']`
3. Your function can return the result containing the employees that meet the specified conditions. This then allows you to invoke the function as and when desired.

Here is an example solution that follows the above corrections/recommendations:

```
data = [
    {
        "name" : "Nauman",
        "age" : 27,
        "salary": 29000
    },
    {
        "name": "Bilal",
        "age": 26,
        "salary": 27000
    },
    {
        "name": "Ali",
        "age": 19,
        "salary": 22000
    },
    {
        "name": "Usman",
        "age": 28,
        "salary": 34000
    },
    {
        "name": "Usama",
        "age": 14,
        "salary": 24000
    }]


def retrieve_desired_employees(employees):
    result = []
    for employee in employees:
        if employee['age'] > 25 and employee['salary'] > 25000:
            result.append(employee)
    return result

print(retrieve_desired_employees(data))
```

If the keys `age` and `salary` are not guaranteed to be in the dictionaries then you can use the dictionary's `get` method to supply a default value.

Here is a modified example:

```
def retrieve_desired_employees(employees):
    result = []
    for employee in employees:
        if employee.get('age', 0) > 25 and employee.get('salary', 0) > 25000:
            result.append(employee)
    return result
```

Answer (score 3):

This helps:

```
def function(employee):
    for value in employee:
        if value["age"] > 25 and value["Salary"] > 25000:
            empty_list.append(value)

function(employee)
```

But better do it with return:

```
def function(listof:list)->list:
    empty_list = []
    for value in listof:
        if value["age"] > 25 and value["Salary"] > 25000:
            empty_list.append(value)
    return empty_list

print(function(employee))
```

As per a comment from [toppk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744864/toppk), this can be consolidate into a list comprehension:

```py
result = [employee for employees in employees if employee.get('age',0) >25 and employee.get('Salary',0) > 25000]
```

Comment: that looks good, although I would use a comprehension, and if he means that age or salary may not always be there, you can you dict.get() instead of ['age'], for example: `result = [employee for employees in employees if employee.get('age',0) >25 and employee.get('Salary',0) > 25000]`